QGIS - cloud masking and how to mosaic
I have downloaded two Landsat 8 images for the year 2015 (one from May and one from July) from Earth Explorer and they both have minimal cloud cover. I'm at the pre-processing stage, where I want to have a clean and cloud-free image for easier land cover classification. I already used the "Cloud Masking" plugin in QGIS and removed the clouds, which left me with a hollow Landsat image of May 2010. Now I want to mosaic the July 2010 image to fill in the hollow or blank spaces in that May 2010 image.
I already tried the "SAGA Raster Tools - Mosaicking" in QGIS but it won't work. Does anyone know a solution to this problem? Google Earth Engine seems like a plausible option to solve this but I am not sure.

Use QGIS processing tool - GDAL | Raster miscellaneous | Merge. Ensure the May 2010 image is at the top, July image is 2nd in the layer list. Ensure both have NoData set correctly.
